# text file into dynamic array

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, malloc

I have found this code from a youtube video and it seemed pretty great but when I rewrote it it doesn't work. It is supposed to read a text file and put it into a dynamic array but the output is nonsensical and outputs seemingly random lower and uppercase letters and symbols like "?" and "!".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\varga\\CLionProjects\\untitled3\\subor.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }

    size_t total = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        fgetc(file);
        total++;
    }

    char *string = malloc(total);
    rewind(file);
    size_t index = 0;

    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        string[index] = fgetc(file);
        index++;
    }

    string[index - 1] = "\0";

    fclose(file);

    printf("File concents: \n\n");
    printf("%s\n", string);

    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you read this: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/12149471) I have removed the redundant information from the question.

Comment: Please note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**. This is rather important when comparing the returned value with the `int` value `EOF`. If you're unlucky, that comparison will actually not work, and you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: On a different note, your reading loops reads ***two*** characters each iteration. You skip every second character from the input file.

Comment: And `string[index - 1] = "\0"` will *not* do what you expect. Please take some time to think about the difference between `'\0'` and `"\0"`.

Comment: When opening the file fails, you print an error message, but you continue program execution as if it suceeded. I suggest that you exit the program immediately instead, for example by writing `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` immediately after `printf("Error");`.

Comment: Consider carefully whether allocating memory and reading the entire file is truly necessary. On POSIX systems, using `mmap` is the right tool for the job. The file may be much larger than the memory that can be allocated.

Comment: Do not use `rewind`; there is no error indication. Instead, use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`